# How we can use FlexboxLayout for API 14

Tags: android, flexbox, android-flexboxlayout

I want to use FlexboxLayout for API 14 but i have faced some issue with `ViewCompat` class means  `ViewCompat.combineMeasuredStates` method not available for api 14.
so how i can use this ?

Answer (score 1):

`minSdkVersion` of [`FlexboxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) [is declared 9](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/build.gradle#L33), which means you should see no issues using it in API 14. Nevertheless, you can see the implementation of `ViewCompat` class and substitute it with your implementation, in this case instead of calling [`ViewCompat.combineMeasuredStates(int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#combineMeasuredStates(int,%20int)) call [`View.combineMeasuredStates(int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#combineMeasuredStates(int,%20int)).

Additionally, as seen [in the docs of ViewCompat.combineMeasuredState(int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#combineMeasuredStates(int,%20int)):

> This method was deprecated in API level 26.0.0-alpha1.
>   Use combineMeasuredStates(int, int) directly.